# Prove that the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear if and only if its coordinate functions $f_1,...,f_m$ are linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

- Prove that the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear if and only if its coordinate functions $f_1,...,f_m$ are linear.

  To prove the question, assume that the following theorem is proven: The mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear if and only if there exists a matrix $A$ such that $f(x)=Ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt. $(\Rightarrow)$. Assume the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear. By the theorem there exists a matrix $A$ such that $f(x)=Ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. So

$$
f_1(x+y)=a_{11}(x_1+y_1)+...+a_{1n}(x_n+y_n)=(a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n)+(a_{11}y_1+...+a_{1n}y_n)
=f_1(x)+f_1(y),
\\ \vdots \\ 
f_m(x+y)=a_{1m}(x_1+y_1)+...+a_{mn}(x_n+y_n)
=f_m(x)+f_m(y)
$$

Similarly, $cf(x)=f(cx)$. So, its coordinate functions $f_1,...,f_m$ are linear

$(\Leftarrow)$. Assume the coordinate functions $f_1,...,f_m$ are linear.So how can I show the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear?

**Can you check my attempt?**

Comment: Observe that for each $\;j\,,\,\,f_j:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;$ is a linear functional....

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to the first direction is missing the proof of the homogeneity condition (that $f_i(\lambda x)=\lambda f_i(x)$), but the addition is ok.

However, you're using a handgun at a knife fight. Why not simply use the definition of linear function?

For shorter notation, let us write $f(x)=(f_i(x))_i$. I'll also use a shorter condition for linearity (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences)

Then
\begin{align*}
f\text{ is linear}&\iff f(x+\lambda y)=f(x)+\lambda f(y)&\text{for all }x,y,\lambda\\
&\iff (f_i(x+\lambda y))_i=(f_i(x))_i+\lambda(f_i(y))&\text{for all }x,y,\lambda\tag{1}\\
&\iff (f_i(x+\lambda y))_i=(f_i(x)+\lambda f_i(y))_i&\text{for all }x,y,\lambda\tag{2}\\
&\iff f_i(x+\lambda y)=f_i(x)+\lambda f_i(y)&\text{for all }x,y,\lambda\text{ and }i\tag{3}\\
&\iff f_i\text{ is linear}&\text{ for all }i\tag{4}
\end{align*}
where $x$ and $y$ denote vectors and $\lambda$ denotes an scalar. (1) follows from the definition of $f$; (2) follows from the definition of the operations on $\mathbb{R}^m$; (e) follows because two $m$-tuples are equal iff respective coordinates are equal; (4) follows from the definition of linearity.

This more abstract approach, which is easier in my opinion, works in general for linear maps between products of vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for comments and answer.

Comment: I was hoping your answer would be reaccepted.

Comment: @copper.hat That's not a problem at all. The approaches are different, and yours seems more elementary. The OP may choose whatever answer he thinks is best, and it is fair to assume other people at the same level as the OP may find yours better as well. Thanks for your worries. \*unclenches fist\*

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that uses the result you were given:

Suppose the $f_k$ are linear. Then the theorem says there is a matrix $a_k$ such that
$f_k(x) = a_k x $ for all $x$. Now let
$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\phi(x) = Ax$ is linear
and $[\phi(x)]_k = a_k x = f_k(x)$, so we have $\phi=f$ and hence $f$ is linear.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: Oops, I did not mean to usurp Luiz's perfectly good answer.

Comment: @copper.hat \*waves clenched fist in the air\*

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: Sorry, entirely unintended.

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet: If you were to reassign the chosen answer I would not mind at all.